# Retrieve Remmina password from Ubuntu keyring in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, ubuntu-18.04, python-keyring

I can add passwords to Ubuntu's system keyring, retrievable by Ansible, with the command

```
keyring set myservice username
```

by installing`sudo apt install python-keyring`. This password is then retrievable within an Ansible playbook for example using

```
ansible_become_pass: "{{ lookup('keyring','myservice username') }}"
```

See the [documentation page](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/keyring.html) for more examples.

But I reinstalled a local computer and I want to re-install/configure a VNC server in it via Ansible. I would like to pick up the saved VNC password that already exists in my computer's (the client) keyring, because I don't want to have the password in plaintext in the middle of a playbook. This password was saved in the keyring by Remmina and does not follow the python-keyring format.

Is there a way to retrieve this password from within an Ansible playbook?

Comment: You could try to use something like (first example I came over, more search needed) https://github.com/drafnel/gnome-keyring-cli from shell. Meanwhile, since we are talking about a single password here, I suggest your get it manually from your keyring with gnome gui tool, encrypt it with [`ansible-vault encrypt-string`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/vault.html) and add it to your playbook. Note that you can strore your ansible-vault [password in your keyring](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/vault.html#vault-password-client-scripts)

Comment: Yea, but I was hoping for a solution with less friction...